# OSX: C scripts compile but I'm having a linker error

Tags: c, gcc, terminal, linker

I'm having trouble compiling two C scripts. I have downloaded the files [here](https://github.com/labjack/exodriver/tree/master/examples/U3), which are a set of examples that are supposed to allow me to interface with a LabJack. I currently have `u3.h`, `u3.c`, and `lj.c` (code shown below) in my directory. The `u3.h` and `u3.c` files are quite long so I found it inappropriate to show the whole thing.

Instead, I wanted to show what is included in the `c` file because I think this is where I'm misunderstanding something.

```
#include "u3.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
```

And here is what's at the top of the header file:

```
#ifndef U3_H_
#define U3_H_

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "labjackusb.h"
```

The file `lj.c` is shown below.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include "u3.h"
#include "labjackusb.h"

int main() {
  HANDLE hDevice;
  int localID;

  // Open first available usb-connected U3
  localID = -1;
  hDevice = openUSBConnection(localID);

  // If connection is invalid, terminate program
  if (hDevice == NULL)
    goto done;

  done:
    return 0;
}
```

The error that I'm having is when I attempt to link the files in the terminal, although each one compiles individually. In the terminal I use

```
$ gcc lj.c u3.c -o test
```

and I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_LJUSB_CloseDevice", referenced from:
      _openUSBConnection in u3-fab2dd.o
      _closeUSBConnection in u3-fab2dd.o
  "_LJUSB_GetDevCount", referenced from:
      _openUSBConnection in u3-fab2dd.o
  "_LJUSB_OpenDevice", referenced from:
      _openUSBConnection in u3-fab2dd.o
  "_LJUSB_Read", referenced from:
      _openUSBConnection in u3-fab2dd.o
      _getCalibrationInfo in u3-fab2dd.o
      _I2C in u3-fab2dd.o
      _ehConfigIO in u3-fab2dd.o
      _ehFeedback in u3-fab2dd.o
      _ehConfigTimerClock in u3-fab2dd.o
  "_LJUSB_Write", referenced from:
      _openUSBConnection in u3-fab2dd.o
      _getCalibrationInfo in u3-fab2dd.o
      _I2C in u3-fab2dd.o
      _ehConfigIO in u3-fab2dd.o
      _ehFeedback in u3-fab2dd.o
      _ehConfigTimerClock in u3-fab2dd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, and I've looked online but I haven't found any solution that I can understand and try to implement.

Comment: None of the 3000+ existing questions and answers here found by searching for *Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64* were able to help?

Comment: I thought I had dealt with the Labjack library already, but it seems I wasn't understanding the problem. The answer provided by duskwuff was very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link against the actual LabJack library. The source files for this library are present in the [`liblabjackusb`](https://github.com/labjack/exodriver/tree/master/liblabjackusb) directory of the repository; alternatively, you can include `labjackusb.c` in your application.

You will also need to link against libusb. This is a separate project, and can be installed on a Mac through tools like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: I added the `labjack.c` file to my directory but I was still getting errors with `libusb`. I had previously installed it and assumed it was in my systems directory but maybe it wasn't. I just specified the library with `gcc lj.c u3.c labjackusb.c -o cff_c \`pkg-config --libs --cflags libusb-1.0\` ` and that seemed to work. Not sure why it it wouldn't link like other libraries would though.

Comment: libusb isn't a standard component of macOS, so it's normal that you'd have to use pkg-config to link against it.